# Getting a blank screen instead of a MapsForge map

Tags: java, android, maps

I am trying to implement the **MapsForge** library to my application and I can't succeed in displaying a downloaded map: I am only getting a blank screen with controls for the scale and the zoom level...

I have tried several data files downloaded from the Internet (.map files) with always the same result...

The only clue I have is an error message I can see in the "run" tab :

```
 W/DatabaseRenderer: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
```

I tried to find information about this error via an Internet search but I didn't get any solution. Hope one of you will know how I could get rid of this problem.

The code I use :

```
    AndroidGraphicFactory.createInstance(getActivity().getApplication());

    fragmentView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_view,null);

    mMap= fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.myMap);
    mMap.setClickable(true);
    mMap.getMapScaleBar().setVisible(true);
    mMap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mMap.setCenter(new LatLong(45.48,3));
    mMap.setZoomLevel((byte)10);

    mTileCache= AndroidUtil.createTileCache(getActivity(), "mapcache", mMap.getModel().displayModel.getTileSize(), 1f, mMap.getModel().frameBufferModel.getOverdrawFactor());

    mapsData= new MapFile(new File("myDirectory/myFile.map"));
    mTileRenderer= new TileRendererLayer(mTileCache, mapsData, mMap.getModel().mapViewPosition, AndroidGraphicFactory.INSTANCE);
    mTileRenderer.setXmlRenderTheme(InternalRenderTheme.DEFAULT);

    mMapo.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(mTileRenderer);

    mMap.setCenter(new LatLong(45.48, 3.05));
    mMap.setZoomLevel((byte) 12);
```

And the dependencies I use :

mapsforge-core-0.9.1

mapsforge-poi-android-0.9.1

mapsforge-map-0.9.1

mapsforge-map-android-0.9.1

mapsforge-map-reader-0.9.1

svg-android-0.4.3

Comment: Please add some code. Did you try [official example](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Android-App.md)?

Comment: Yes. Code added.

Comment: I mean source code.

Comment: That's exactly what I was adding... You have been too fast!

Comment: Are you sure that this `new File("myDirectory/myFile.map")` gives you the file you are trying to use?

Comment: Yes, the file is correctly loaded. I have checked it's bounding box, among other parameters, and it is correct.

Comment: In fact, the problem seems related to the process of loading the map. The bounding box is not correct : the min latitude and longitude are correct for the map loaded, but the corresponding max parameters are equals to the min ones. The result is a zero size map, and that's certainly the root of the problem. When could I find a map which should lead to a correct display?

Comment: Problem solved!! It wasn't related to the map file but to the xml render file which were missing. Now that I have downloaded them, the map is correctly displayed. Thanks to all of you who spent time trying to help me.